# iOS 16 Safari - How do I hide the toolbar completely?

Tags: ios, safari, web-browser

I'm on iOS 16 developer beta 3 (20A5312g), and I need to hide the toolbar in Safari *completely* for a specific purpose. Tapping `Hide Toolbar` won't hide it completely.

Can I do it in Safari? If not, is there an alternative browser that supports this?